# Connections between interpretations of theories

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask if questions about connections between different interpretations of physical theories can be posted(let me be exact: an example of a question like that is "What are the connections between Relational and Bohmian Quantum Mechanics?).

Thank you.

Comment: For the general answer, see ACuriousJim's answer. For the specific questino you want to ask, I'd say it is *too broad* - it is neither clear what exactly a "connection" is supposed to be and whether some, many, or none exist.

Comment: Just to back up what ACuriousMind says: a question here should have a concise answer. If answering the question would require writing an essay then the question is likely to be flagged as too broad. If you just ask *What are the connections between Relational and Bohmian Quantum Mechanics?* that's really too broad.

Answer (score 3):

There's potential for such a question to be too broad or opinion-based. But as long as you keep it concise and on-topic, it should be fine. There isn't anything wrong with the type of question per se. Just be careful with what and how you ask things.